# How to create customize popup using absolute layout?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Is there a way to use absolute layout as a customize pop-up? I am trying to create a customize popup. Is this possible?

```
<StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" BackgroundColor="Yellow">
    //Elements here
</StackLayout>
<AbsoluteLayout StyleClass="dialogbox" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
   //Popup here         
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

Comment: You can use the plugin Rg.Plugins.Popup to create custom pop ups and dialogs. Link: https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup

Comment: @SparshaBhattarai is there a way to animate content view? for example My contentview is set to "isvisible = false" and when I click the button the content view will fade in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that with `AbsoluteLayout` and add a fade animation. Here is running GIF.

[image]

There is code.

```
      <StackLayout>

    <Button
        x:Name="btn"
        Text="click"
        />

    <ContentView x:Name="popupLoginView" BackgroundColor="#C0808080" Padding="10, 0" IsVisible="false" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0, 0, 1, 1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All">
        <AbsoluteLayout  VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center">
            <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" HeightRequest="200" WidthRequest="300" BackgroundColor="White">
                <Entry Margin="20,20,20,10" Placeholder="Enter Username"></Entry>
                <Entry Margin="20,0,20,0" Placeholder="Enter Password"></Entry>
                <Button Margin="20,0,20,0" Text="Login"></Button>

            </StackLayout>
        </AbsoluteLayout>
    </ContentView>
</StackLayout>
```

In xamarin forms, you can add fade animation to view. There is animation code.

```
 public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
      btn.Clicked += Btn_Clicked;
    }




    private async void Btn_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (popupLoginView.IsVisible==true)
        {
            btn.IsEnabled = false;
              await popupLoginView.FadeTo(0,2000);
            await Task.Delay(2000);
            popupLoginView.Opacity = 0;
            popupLoginView.IsVisible = false;

            btn.IsEnabled = true;
            return;


        }
        if (popupLoginView.IsVisible == false)
        {

            if (popupLoginView.Opacity==1)
            {
                popupLoginView.Opacity = 0;
            }

            popupLoginView.IsVisible = true;
            btn.IsEnabled = false;
            await popupLoginView.FadeTo(1, 2000);
              await Task.Delay(2000);
            btn.IsEnabled = true;
            popupLoginView.Opacity = 1;
            return;

        }


    }
}
```

There is article about fade animation.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/animation/simple#fading

If you want to achieve it with `Rg.Plugins.Popup` and add the animation, you can refer to this article, it will add some animations.

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/learn-about-xamarin-forms-animation-with-popuppage/

Comment: is there a way to add fade in?

Comment: @LawrenceAgulto Yes, to achieve fade in, you could set  popupLoginView.Opacity = 1; then set `popupLoginView.FadeTo(0,2000);` I updated my answer, you can refer to it

Comment: @LawrenceAgulto If the answer is helpful, please mark it as answer, it will help others who have similar issue.

Comment: Do i need the task delay?